# My Code using Reinforced Learning (Q) to analyze a grid and give an order of the highest numbers is looping

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Here is the task, in the form I understand it:

I have a grid 5x5 with different numbers. The range for the sake of the example can be from 0 to 9.
I have 100 currency that I can spend, which we will call "NPV", and means the amount of currency we have on hand

Each drill, that is placed in a cell, costs 10 currency.

Using Reinforced learning, I need to create a process, where the agent itself carries out iterations, where each time the grid is updated, the agent chooses the cells with the highest value to place drills and returns the order of placement in a list.

So I have went through endless samples, and I always face the same problem, an "endless" loop. And I cannot figure out what to do in this scenario. Could you please aid me in understanding, what am I missing.

Attempt 1 - total reward parameter doesn't change from -100 (Episode 999: Total Reward = -100)
Initial problematic line:

```
# Choose actions until all drills are placed
    while not done:
        # Choose an action based on the current state
        action = agent.choose_action(current_state)

        # Get the reward for the chosen action
        reward = get_reward(current_state, action)
        total_reward += reward

        # Update the grid
        row = action // 5
        col = action % 5
        grid[row][col] = 1

        # Update the state based on the chosen action
        next_state = action

        # Check if all drills are placed
        if total_reward <= -100:
            done = True

        # Update the Q-table with the chosen action and reward
        agent.learn(current_state, action, reward, next_state, done)

        # Set the current state to the next state
        current_state = next_state

    # Print the total reward for the episode
    print("Episode {}: Total Reward = {}".format(episode, total_reward))
```

Whole code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# define the grid
grid = []
for i in range(5):
    row = []
    for j in range(5):
        row.append(random.randint(0, 9))
    grid.append(row)`

# Print the grid
for row in grid:
    print(row)

# Define the Q-learning agent
class QLearningAgent:
def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate=0.1, discount_factor=0.95, exploration_rate=1.0,
                 exploration_decay_rate=0.99):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.discount_factor = discount_factor
        self.exploration_rate = exploration_rate
        self.exploration_decay_rate = exploration_decay_rate
        self.q_table = np.zeros((state_size, action_size))

    def choose_action(self, state):
        if np.random.uniform(0, 1) < self.exploration_rate:
            # Explore action space
            return np.random.choice(self.action_size)
        else:
            # Exploit learned values
            return np.argmax(self.q_table[state, :])

    def learn(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        current_q_value = self.q_table[state, action]
        next_max_q_value = np.max(self.q_table[next_state, :])
        td_target = reward + self.discount_factor * next_max_q_value * (1 - int(done))
        td_error = td_target - current_q_value
        new_q_value = current_q_value + self.learning_rate * td_error
        self.q_table[state, action] = new_q_value
        if done:
            self.exploration_rate *= self.exploration_decay_rate

# Define the action space as all the cells in the grid
action_space = list(range(25))

def get_reward(state, action):
    npv = 0
    # Check if action is valid (NPV is sufficient and cell is empty)
    row = action // 5
    col = action % 5
    if grid[row][col] == 0 and npv >= 10:
        npv -= 10
        return 10
    else:
        return -10
# Set up
num_episodes = 1000
npv = 100

# Initialize the Q-learning agent
agent = QLearningAgent(state_size=len(action_space), action_size=len(action_space))

# Run the training loop
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    # Reset the environment
    current_state = 0
    total_reward = 0
    done = False

    # Choose actions until all drills are placed
    while not done:
        # Choose an action based on the current state
        action = agent.choose_action(current_state)

        # Get the reward for the chosen action
        reward = get_reward(current_state, action)
        total_reward += reward

        # Update the grid
        row = action // 5
        col = action % 5
        grid[row][col] = 1

        # Update the state based on the chosen action
        next_state = action

        # Check if all drills are placed
        if total_reward <= -100:
            done = True

        # Update the Q-table with the chosen action and reward
        agent.learn(current_state, action, reward, next_state, done)

        # Set the current state to the next state
        current_state = next_state

    # Print the total reward for the episode
    print("Episode {}: Total Reward = {}".format(episode, total_reward))

    # Reset the grid for the next episode
    grid = []
    for i in range(5):
        row = []
        for j in range(5):
            row.append(random.randint(0, 9))
        grid.append(row)
```